# Ionic - ion-google-place display businesses only by type

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using ion-google-place with my Ionic app to fetch business name and locations.  It uses google places api.  Is there a way to set a filter by business type?

https://github.com/israelidanny/ion-google-place